# What do the callback arguments do in JS Async library?

Tags: javascript, callback, async.js

I saw a code that looks like this (Pro Node). It uses [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html) library.

```
var async = require("async");
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Task 1");
      callback(null, 1);
}, 300); },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Task 2");
      callback(null, 2);
    }, 200);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Task 3");
      callback(null, 3);
}, 100); }
], function(error, results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

When I run it, it shows:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

All is well - however, I do not quite understand what the callback lines are: `callback(null, 1)`, `callback(null, 2)`, and `callback(null, 3)`.

If I remove all of those lines, when I run the code it returns only:

```
Task 1
```

What do the first and second arguments do and why are the second arguments `1`, `2`, and `3`?

Comment: Do you know what callbacks are without async.js? Do you know how callbacks in the native node functions work?

Comment: @Bergi, I am not familiar. I used callbacks in the past when with `fetch`, but I haven't explored it. I wasn't sure if this is an async thing or broader javascript thing.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to read a more generic tutorial first - there are dozens out there on how callbacks work in nodejs - e.g. [this one](https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html). For information about why node callbacks have two parameters, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40511513/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the async library, calling the callback function 
of `async.series` runs the next function in the array. The first parameter is any error data. It's a node convention that any errors are the [first parameter](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) to callback functions. The second parameter is the success data, and is passed to the 2nd parameter of the `async.series` callback as an array of all success data.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511513/why-does-node-prefer-error-first-callback) for more details as to why node prefers error first callbacks.

Comment: Awesome. So the first argument = error, and the second is what it returns. Very clear - I understand it now. Thank you so very much!!